Finding the Balancing Point in a Sequence from 1 to n
I am trying to solve a problem where I need to find a specific number k in a sequence from 1 to n such that the sum of numbers from 1 to k−1 is equal to the sum of numbers from k+1 to n.
So given a sequence from 1 to n, I want to find k such that the sum of the numbers to the left of k equals the sum of the numbers to its right.
For example, for n=8, the answer is k=6:
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6], 7, 8)
Here, the sum of numbers from 1 to 5 is 15, and the sum of numbers from 7 to 8 is also 15.
What I have tried so far:
I wrote a function in Python to find this number k:
def find_k(n):
    left_sum = 0
    right_sum = 0
    left_numbers = []
    right_numbers = []

    for k in range(1, n+1):
        left_sum += k
        left_numbers.append(k)
        right_sum += n+1-k
        right_numbers.append(n+1-k)
        if left_sum == right_sum and (right_numbers[-1] - left_numbers[-1] == 2):
            return k+1

    return -1  

# Test case
print(find_k(8))  

However, I am not sure if this approach is correct or optimal. I want to ensure that I am stopping at the correct number and checking the condition properly.

What should happen if there is not such number in sequence?

Not specified but I would just return -1 or None as I did in the code above

To find out if your code is correct, you usually make tests. Make another piece of code which runs your function and checks whether the result is correct. Then run this other code on several test cases. Not sure if this is an answer or a comment. Looks too obvious; maybe I misunderstood the question?

If this approach works correctly (I'm not sure either) it would be hard to explain why. My approach would be to first set the sum of all items except the leftmost one as right_sum, left_sum starts with 0, k with 1. Compare it. If not equal, add k to left_sum, increment k, subtract k from right_sum, back to comparison and so on.

Some math will show that the answer is sqrt(n(n+1)/2).
Proof:
You have numbers 1, 2, ..., k-1, k, k+1, ... n and you want to find k such that (1 + 2 + ... + k-1) = (k+1 + ... +n). These sums can be calculated by taking the average (which is half the sum of the first and last number of the sequence) times the number of numbers.
(1 + k - 1) / 2 * (k-1) = (k + 1 + n)/2 * (n - k)
Simplify:
k*(k-1) / 2 = (n + k + 1) / 2 * (n - k)
Multiply both sides by 2 and simplify:
k**2 - k = n**2 - k**2 + n - k
2k**2 = n**2 + n
k = sqrt(n * (n + 1) / 2))
Then of course, check that k is an integer.
Visual Proof:
Represent our number as an k x k square (for our example, we'll use the 6x6).

Remove the last row, then split the above k-1 x k square in half into complementary staircases. Here, we all already see that the green staircase plus the last row makes a staircase of k-steps.

Since our number was the sum of a sequence 1, 2, ... n. That means it must be able to be represented as a staircase of n steps. We've already built up that staircase up to k steps, so the remaining steps must be able to be built from the remaining blue squares.


Also funny side note: n * (n + 1) / 2 is the sum of the complete sequence. So, the balancing point can be calculated just by taking the square root of the sum of sequence. Thats interesting.

@lord_haffi Yeah, made me wonder whether there's a nice "visual proof"...

It also means that a balancing point only exists if the sum of the sequence is a square number. I believe there is some geometric shit going on there :D

I just wrote a little program. It seems that the existence of a balancing point is extremely rare. It calculated all sequences with length n up to 10 Mio. which have one and the result is: {8: 6, 49: 35, 288: 204, 1681: 1189, 9800: 6930, 57121: 40391, 332928: 235416, 1940449: 1372105}. Where the projection is n -> balancing point index. Only 8 out of the first 10 Mio sequences have a balancing point. Wild :D

@lord_haffi You'll find a simple fast way to compute these if you search the sequence in OEIS.

@nocomment Thanks for the hint! Didn't knew about this great database :) It seems that it's somewhat related to Pythagorean triples. So there may be a nice visual proof.

@lord_haffi I have come up with a visual proof.

@MichaelCao Looks great! :) Additionally, you may refer to the term "triangle numbers" (just realized it) for any one looking for more research.

What is that Visual Proof supposed to prove?

If a number is both a square and the sum of an arithmetic sequence of 1, 2, ... n, then that number can be subdivided into 1, 2, ... k-1; k; k+1, k+2, ... n such that the first and third sequences have the same sum.

Your code will not work, you are always approaching towards the middle of the array. You need to have two pointers, one pointing to the start, one to the end, and accumulate the sum till the left and another sum till the right (counting from the end). You loop as long as the left and right pointers do not pass each other, in each loop you compare the left and right sum, if the left sum is larger, decrement the right pointer and add to the right sum and vice versa. If at the end you find that the left and right sums are equal and the left and right pointers difference is 2, then you're good.

A slice-and-sum approach which is still true for non-arithmetic sequences, so for more general ones.
l = list(range(1, 8+1)) # test sequence

for i in range(1, len(l)-1):
    if sum(l[:i]) == sum(l[i+1:]):
        print(l[:i], l[i+1:])
        break

